# Array of tags in JSON

Tags: python, arrays, json

How can I put this `[IT,trends]` in Python in a form of JSON dumps?

That is what I have in the documentation:

> topics    String[]    example: [IT,trends]    array of Topic names (tags) for the Node

I am trying the following but it doesn't work (I am doing a request to an API):

```
values = dumps({
        "title": "question title",
        "body": "body title",
        "username": "3100002UNY",
        "topics": ("SPSS","TEST")
        })
```

When I put only one topic...it works good! But I need to put more than one. Any idea?

Comment: In Python, `()` defines a tuple.  JSON might require a list, e.g. `[]`  Hmmm, that doesn't seem to be the problem.  You're getting an API error, not a Python error, right?

Answer (score 0):

This is another example:

```
    from urllib2 import Request, urlopen
from json import dumps
values = dumps({
    "title": "How to make a Great Dish?",
    "body": "To please my family&friends...",
    "topics": "cooking",
    "attachments":[{"fileName":"example.png","mimeType":"image/png","content":"/9j/4AAQS....A21C="}]
})
headers = {"Accept": "application/json", "Content-type": "application/json"}
request = Request("http://private-4f9cf-answerhubapiv2.apiary-mock.com/services/v2/question[.json|.xml]", data=values, headers=headers)
response_body = urlopen(request).read()
print response_body
```

How can I put multiple topics?